# Is there a way of having arithmetic operators use getters and setters in Javascript ES6?

Tags: javascript, getter-setter, assignment-operator, es6-class

I have a rudimentary ID system where a number is translated into a string and padded with zeros to be at least 3 digits. It works fine as long as I'm only using a regular assignment. Is there any way of having arithmetic operators work with the setter as well?

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.id = 0;
  }

  /**
   * @param {Number} num
   */
  set id(num) {
    if (num < 10) {
      this._id = '00' + num;
    } else if (num < 100) {
      this._id = '0' + num;
    } else {
      this._id = '' + num;
    }
  }

  get id() {
    return this._id;
  }

  incrementID(increment=1) {
    const id = parseInt(this.id);
    this.id = id + increment;
  }
}

const test = new Test();
test.id = 5;
console.log(`ID is: ${test.id}`); // ID is: 005

test.id += 5;
console.log(`ID is: ${test.id}`); // ID is: 00055 (How?!?)
```

I know I could have an `incrementID` method like the one I wrote, but that feels like it's against the philosophy that ES6 setters and getters have.

As a side note, what is even happening with the addition assignment? I would've expected the result to be `0055` if anything weird, since it's a number being added to a string.

Comment: as per your logic, "005" + 5 turns to "0055", which as number is 55, which is smaller than 100, gets prepended with "0", and turns to "00055". String conversion is your issue.

Comment: No, there's no way to avoid this but to have a numeric `.id` property and a *separate* `paddedId` string getter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, *theoretically* you could make 'id' an object and provide a hook to convert it to a number by default:

```js
class ID {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint) {
        if (hint === 'number' || hint === 'default')
            return Number(this.value)
        return String(this.value);
    }
}

class Test {
    constructor() {
        this.id = new ID('000');
    }

    set id(num) {
        let s;
        if (num < 10) {
            s = '00' + num;
        } else if (num < 100) {
            s = '0' + num;
        } else {
            s = '' + num;
        }
        this._id = new ID(s);

    }

    get id() {
        return this._id;
    }
}


const test = new Test();
test.id = 5;
console.log(`ID is: ${test.id}`); // ID is: 005

test.id += 5;
console.log(`ID is: ${test.id}`); // ID is: 010
```

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toPrimitive)

That said, a practical way would be to have two properties (number and a formatted string), as suggested above.

Answer (score 1):

Your getter and setter *are* being used. Here's what's happening.

```
testid += 5;
```

is translated to

```
test.id = test.id + 5
```

This first calls the getter, which returns `"005"`. It then concatenates `5`, resulting in `"0055"`. So it's equivalent to:

```
test.id = "0055";
```

In the setter, it gets to this test:

```
if (num < 100)
```

This is true because 55 is less than 100. So it does:

```
this._id = '0' + num;
```

This concatenates `0` to the front, so it assigns `"00055"`.

You could solve this problem by having the getter first convert `num` to an integer.

```
  set id(num) {
    num = parseInt(num);
    if (num < 10) {
      this._id = '00' + num;
    } else if (num < 100) {
      this._id = '0' + num;
    } else {
      this._id = '' + num;
    }
  }
```

But there's no way to make `+=` convert the string to a number before doing the increment. The getter doesn't know how you're going to use the value, it can't return something different when the property is part of an increment operation.